# The selected company is not compatible with the companies of the related user(s)

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I got the below error when refreshed the server. I haven't changed the code. I just selected a company other than "Your company". Now, with this error, I can no longer access my Odoo server.

```
File "/home/amr/odoo12/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/res_partner.py", line 555, in write
    raise UserError(
odoo.exceptions.UserError: ('The selected company is not compatible with the companies of the related user(s)', '')
```

Comment: Go to setting> user and check your login user company.

Comment: did u solve it? I have the same problem